Syntax error: does not provide an export named 'useHistory'
I'm trying to use useHistory hook to protect the routes in the ReactJs Vite app, but receiving an error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module
'/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=6b9126db' does not
provide an export named 'useHistory'

I use JWT for login in and save the token in the localStorage.
This is my code:
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function AdminNews() {

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (!token) {
      history.push("/login");
  }}, [history]);

  //rest of the code 
}


If you are using React-Router-DOM v6 then the useHistory hook was replaced by the useNavigate hook.
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function AdminNews() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (!token) {
      navigate("/login");
  }}, [navigate]);

  //rest of the code 
}

RRDv6 has a lot of breaking changes from v4/5 so you may want to review the Main Concepts and Migration Guide for complete details.
If you did not intend to install RRDv6 then you can revert back to v5.

npm uninstall react-router-dom
npm install react-router-dom@5 and restart app

